# how to use shell to copy file with certain name requirements to the immediate parent directory

Tags: bash, shell

how to use shell copy all the files that start with the some string
 followed by three numbers and ending with any sequence of three characters
after a dot ( from the current directory to
the immediate parent directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main challenge here is to get a list of files.

So you are looking at files with:

```
<SOMESTRING><digit><digit><digit>.<char><char><char>
```

My first reflex was to do:

```
/bin/ls somestring[[:digit:]]{3}.[[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]][[:alpha:]]
```

Then Benjamin W. pointed out that "character" can include numbers, so:

```
/bin/ls somestring[[:digit:]]{3}.???
```

But that does not work since `ls` uses globing, not regular expressions.  So it must be modified like this:

```
/bin/ls somestring[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]].???
```

Works but not very elegant IMHO.  So you can then do this:

```
find . -regextype posix-awk -regex ".*[0-9]{3}\..{3}" -print
```

Once you have your list of files, you can use cp to copy them to directory "..", which designates the parent directory.  That part is left to you complete, the hard part is done :-)

Comment: "Any three characters" isn't just letters, I'd say, so `.???` would work.

Comment: Also, there's a typo, last `[[:digit:]]` missing second closing `]`.

Comment: Ah, but for regex you can't use `?`, that one should probably be `[[:digit:]]{3}\....`

Comment: Indeed, I tested before correcting, and I saw that.  I posted with `.{3}`